# color founding multiple colours

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, colors

I first created a dictionary of 21 different color codes with their names

```
rgb_colors = {"Red":[1.0,0.0,0.0],"Green":[0.0,1.0,0.0],"Blue":[0.0,0.0,1.0],
             "Black":[0.0,0.0,0.0],"Almond":[0.94,0.87,0.8],"White":[1.0,1.0,1.0],
            "Brown":[0.8,0.5,0.2],"Cadet":[0.33,0.41,0.47],"Camel":[0.76,0.6,0.42],
            "Capri":[0.0,0.75,1.0],"Cardinal":[0.77,0.12,0.23],"Ceil":[0.57,0.63,0.81],
            "Celadon":[0.67,0.88,0.69],"Champagne":[0.97,0.91,0.81],"Charcoal":[0.21,0.27,0.31],
            "Cream":[1.0,0.99,0.82],"Cyan":[0.0,1.0,1.0],"DarkBlue":[0.0,0.0,0.55],
            "AmericanRose":[1.0,0.01,0.24],"Gray":[0.5,0.5,0.5],"Wenge":[0.39,0.33,0.32]}
```

Then I converted it to Df

```
RGB = pd.DataFrame(rgb_colors.items(), columns = ["Color","Color Code"])
```

Then I created a list of all the color codes
and asked for input code. then I used the input color and and found the Euclidean distance between each color code to the input and asset a threshold to select the code that matches at least 60% and used the top three codes as the closest colour.

```
#list of colors
list_of_rgb = [[1.0,0.0,0.0],[0.0,1.0,0.0],[0.0,0.0,1.0],[0.0,0.0,0.0],[0.94,0.87,0.8],
                 [1.0,1.0,1.0],[0.8,0.5,0.2],[0.33,0.41,0.47],[0.76,0.6,0.42],
                  [0.0,0.75,1.0],[0.77,0.12,0.23],[0.57,0.63,0.81],
                  [0.67,0.88,0.69],[0.97,0.91,0.81],[0.21,0.27,0.31],
                  [1.0,0.99,0.82],[0.0,1.0,1.0],[0.0,0.0,0.55],[1.0,0.01,0.24]
                  ,[0.5,0.5,0.5],[0.39,0.33,0.32]]
#input color
print("Enter R,G,B color codes")
color1 = []
for i in range(0,3):
    ele = float(input())
    color1.append(ele)
      
print(color1)

def closest(colors,color, threshold=60, max_return=3):
    colors = np.array(colors)
    color = np.array(color)
    distances = np.sqrt(np.sum((colors-color)**2,axis=1))
    boolean_masks = distances < (1.0 - (threshold / 100))
    outputs = colors[boolean_masks]
    output_distances = distances[boolean_masks]
    return outputs[np.argsort(output_distances)][:max_return]

closest_color = closest(list_of_rgb, color1)

closest_color
```

suppose the Input is `[0.52,0.5,0.5]`
then closest colors are

```
array([[0.5 , 0.5 , 0.5 ],
       [0.76, 0.6 , 0.42],
       [0.8 , 0.5 , 0.2 ]])
```

My question is, how can I find how much percentage of each of these closest color should be used to get the input color?

It can be solved by finding 3 proportions p1,p2 and p3 such that p1+p2+p3=1 and

p1*(r1,g1,b1) + p2*(r2,g2,b2) + p3*(r3,g3,b3) = (r0,g0,b0)

I'm unable to find p1,p2 and p3. Can anyone help me out on how can I find the p values?

Comment: Can you not use the distances from the input colour? Let's say the closest colours are a 95% match, 80% match and 66% match. You could use 95/241 for the first colour, 80/241 for the second and 66/241 for the third. What would that look like?

Comment: @tcotts not quite, because the distance is computed on 3 orthogonal dimension, and the colors will in general contribute differently to the 3 dims.

Comment: Your model is incorrect.

Comment: @Vitalizzare Can you explain what did I do wrong?

Comment: @Jeeth Forget about colors, look at this as a set of vectors. What you ask is switchin between bases. You can't do it voluntaraly just taking closest three. Also you can't be sure that in the new basys the coordinates will satisfy requirements to be in [0, 1] and have the sum equal 1, as if they are proportions of some mix. Also your grid (a set of predifined colors) is too spars and somewhat "linear". Almost all colors can there can be approximated by one plane. You'll never reach this way colors like #ff00ff or #ffff00.

Comment: Likely, you want to average the colors rather than just summing them. Otherwise I see no point for including `[0, 0, 0]` as this will never contribute to getting to the desired color if the combination of colors is through summation.

Comment: @Vitalizzare I think the colors are in float representatio, i.e. `#ff0000` is `(1.0, 0.0, 0.0)` (aside of some switching of the channels).

Comment: @norok2 Right, that's what I mean. The color `#ff00ff` is `(1,0,1)`. Let's see what's the minimal distance it has from others: `df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(rgb_colors, 'index', columns=[*'RGB']); print(np.linalg.norm(df - [1,0,1], axis=1).min())`  I got the answer `0.76`, which mean there's no representatitves of the set in the 0.4 sphere around this point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [system of linear equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_of_linear_equations) you are setting up is over-determined, meaning that in general there is no solution.
The additional constraints on the proportions (or more precisely weights) -- summing up to 1, being in the [0, 1] range -- make things worse because even in case a solution exists, it may be discarded because of those additional constraints.

The question in its current form is not mathematically solvable.

---

Whether you want to include a fixed sum constraints or not, the mathematics for finding the best weights for a linear combination is very similar and although exact solutions are not always attainable, it is possible get to approximate solutions.

One way of computing the is through linear programming, which gets you essentially to [@greenerpastures's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73588254/5218354), but requires you to use linear programming.

---

## Using Brute Force and Simple Least Squares

Here I propose a more basic approach where only simple linear algebra is involved, but ignores the requirement for the weights being in the `[0, 1]` range (which may be introduced afterwards).

The equations for writing a *target* color `b` as a linear combination of colors can be written in matrix form as:

```
A x = b
```

with `A` formed by the colors you want to use, `b` is the *target* color and `x` are the weights.

```
/ r0 r1 r2 \                / r_ \
| g0 g1 g2 | (x0, x1, x2) = | g_ |
\ b0 b1 b2 /                \ b_ /
```

Now, this system of equations admits a single solution if `det(A) != 0`.
Since among the selected colors there is an ortho-normal basis, you can actually use those to construct an `A` with `det(A) != 0`, and hence a `x` can always be found.
If the elements of `b` are in the `[0, 1]` range, so are the elements of `x`, because essentially `b = x`.

In general, you can find the solution of the `Ax = b` linear system of equations with [`np.linalg.solve()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.solve.html), which can be used to look for `x` when `A` is formed by other colors, as long as `det(A) != 0`.

If you want to include more or less than as many colors as the number of channels, then **approximate** solutions minimizing the sum of squares can be obtained with [`np.linalg.lstsq()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.lstsq.html) which implements [least squares approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_squares): finds the best weights to assign to `n` vectors (`components`), such that their linear combination (weighted sum) is as close as possible (minimizes the sum of squares) to the `target` vector.

Once you are set to find approximate solution, the *requirement* on the sum of the weights becomes an additional parameter in the system of linear equation.

This can be included by simply augmenting `A` and `b` with an extra dimension set to `1` for `A` and to `q` for `b`, so that `A x = b` becomes:

```
/ r0 r1 r2 \                / r3 \
| g0 g1 g2 | (p0, p1, p2) = | g3 |
| b0 b1 b2 |                | b3 |
\  1  1  1 /                \  q /
```

Now the new equation `p0 + p1 + p2 = q` is included.

While all this can work with arbitrary colors, the ones selected by closeness are not necessarily going to be good candidates to approximate well an arbitrary color.

For example, if the target color is `(1, 0, 1)` and the 3 closest colors happen to be proportional to each other, say `(0.9, 0, 0)`, `(0.8, 0, 0)`, `(0.7, 0, 0)`, it may be better to use say `(0, 0, 0.5)` which is farther but can contribute better to make a good approximation than say `(0.7, 0, 0)`.

Given that the number of possible combinations is fairly small, it is possible to try out all colors, in groups of fixed increasing size.
This approach is called brute-force, because we try out all of them.
The least squares method is used to find the weights.
Then we can add additional logic to enforce the constraints we want.

To enforce the weights to sum up to one, it is possible to explicitly normalize them.
To restrict them to a particular range, we can discard weights not complying (perhaps with some tolerance `atol` to mitigate numerical issues with float comparisons).

The code would read:

```py
import itertools
import dataclasses
from typing import Optional, Tuple, Callable, Sequence

import numpy as np


def best_linear_approx(target: np.ndarray, components: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    coeffs, _, _, _ = np.linalg.lstsq(components, target, rcond=-1)
    return coeffs


@dataclasses.dataclass
class ColorDecomposition:
    color: np.ndarray
    weights: np.ndarray
    components: np.ndarray
    indices: np.ndarray
    cost: float
    sum_weights: float


def decompose_bf_lsq(
    color: Sequence,
    colors: Sequence,
    max_nums: int = 3,
    min_nums: int = 1,
    min_weights: float = 0.0, 
    max_weights: float = 1.0,
    atol: float = 1e-6,
    norm_in_cost: bool = False,
    force_norm: bool = False,
) -> Optional[ColorDecomposition]:
    """Decompose `color` into a linear combination of a number of `colors`.

    This perfoms a brute-force search.

    Some constraints can be introduced into the decomposition:
     - The weights within a certain range ([`min_weights`, `max_weights`])
     - The weights to accumulate (sum or average) to a certain value.

    The colors are chosen to have minimum sum of squared differences (least squares).

    Additional costs may be introduced in the brute-force search, to favor
    particular solutions when the least squares are the same.

    Args:
        color: The color to decompose.
        colors: The base colors to use for the decomposition.
        max_nums: The maximum number of base colors to use.
        min_weights: The minimum value for the weights.
        max_weights: The maximum value for the weights.
        atol: The tolerance on the weights.
        norm_in_cost: Include the norm in the cost for the least squares.
        force_norm: If True, the weights are normalized to `acc_to`, if set.
        weight_costs: The additional weight costs to prefer specific solutions.

    Returns:
        The resulting color decomposition.
    """
    color = np.array(color)
    colors = np.array(colors)
    num_colors, num_channels = colors.shape
    # augment color/colors
    if norm_in_cost:
        colors = np.concatenate(
            [colors, np.ones(num_colors, dtype=colors.dtype)[:, None]],
            axis=1,
        )
        color = np.concatenate([color, np.ones(1, dtype=colors.dtype)])
    # brute-force search
    best_indices = None
    best_weights = np.zeros(1)
    best_cost = np.inf
    for n in range(min_nums, max_nums + 1):
        for indices in itertools.combinations(range(num_colors), n):
            if np.allclose(color, np.zeros_like(color)):
                # handles the 0 case
                weights = np.ones(n)
            else:
                # find best linear approx
                weights = best_linear_approx(color, colors[indices, :].T)
            # weights normalization
            if force_norm and np.all(weights > 0.0):
                norm = np.sum(weights)
                weights /= norm
            # add some tolerance
            if atol > 0:
                mask = np.abs(weights) > atol
                weights = weights[mask]
                indices = np.array(indices)[mask].tolist()
            if atol > 0 and max_weights is not None:
                mask = (weights > max_weights - atol) & (weights < max_weights + atol)
                weights[mask] = max_weights
            if atol > 0 and min_weights is not None:
                mask = (weights < min_weights + atol) & (weights > min_weights - atol)
                weights[mask] = min_weights
            # compute the distance between the current approximation and the target
            err = color - (colors[indices, :].T @ weights)
            curr_cost = np.sum(err * err)
            if (
                curr_cost <= best_cost
                and (min_weights is None or np.all(weights >= min_weights))
                and (max_weights is None or np.all(weights <= max_weights))
            ):
                best_indices = indices
                best_weights = weights
                best_cost = curr_cost
    if best_indices is not None:
        return ColorDecomposition(
            color=(colors[best_indices, :].T @ best_weights)[:num_channels],
            weights=best_weights,
            components=[c for c in colors[best_indices, :num_channels]],
            indices=best_indices,
            cost=best_cost,
            sum_weights=np.sum(best_weights),
        )
    else:
        return None
```

This can be used as follows:

```py
colors = [
    [1.0, 0.0, 0.0],
    [0.0, 1.0, 0.0],
    [0.0, 0.0, 1.0],
    [0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
    [0.94, 0.87, 0.8],
    [1.0, 1.0, 1.0],
    [0.8, 0.5, 0.2],
    [0.33, 0.41, 0.47],
    [0.76, 0.6, 0.42],
    [0.0, 0.75, 1.0],
    [0.77, 0.12, 0.23],
    [0.57, 0.63, 0.81],
    [0.67, 0.88, 0.69],
    [0.97, 0.91, 0.81],
    [0.21, 0.27, 0.31],
    [1.0, 0.99, 0.82],
    [0.0, 1.0, 1.0],
    [0.0, 0.0, 0.55],
    [1.0, 0.01, 0.24],
    [0.5, 0.5, 0.5],
    [0.39, 0.33, 0.32],
]


some_colors = [[0.9, 0.6, 0.5], [0.52, 0.5, 0.5], [0.5, 0.5, 0.5], [0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1]]
# some_colors = [[0., 0., 0.]]
for color in some_colors:
    print(color)
    print(decompose_bf_lsq(color, colors, max_nums=1))
    print(decompose_bf_lsq(color, colors, max_nums=2))
    print(decompose_bf_lsq(color, colors))
    print(decompose_bf_lsq(color, colors, min_weights=0.0, max_weights=1.0))
    print(decompose_bf_lsq(color, colors, norm_in_cost=True))
    print(decompose_bf_lsq(color, colors, force_norm=True))
    print(decompose_bf_lsq(color, colors, norm_in_cost=True, force_norm=True))
# [0.9, 0.6, 0.5]
# ColorDecomposition(color=array([0.72956991, 0.68444188, 0.60922849]), weights=array([0.75213393]), components=[array([0.97, 0.91, 0.81])], indices=[13], cost=0.048107706898684606, sum_weights=0.7521339326213355)
# ColorDecomposition(color=array([0.9       , 0.60148865, 0.49820272]), weights=array([0.2924357, 0.6075643]), components=[array([1., 0., 0.]), array([1.  , 0.99, 0.82])], indices=[0, 15], cost=5.446293494705139e-06, sum_weights=0.8999999999999999)
# ColorDecomposition(color=array([0.9, 0.6, 0.5]), weights=array([0.17826087, 0.91304348, 0.43478261]), components=[array([0., 0., 1.]), array([0.8, 0.5, 0.2]), array([0.39, 0.33, 0.32])], indices=[2, 6, 20], cost=0.0, sum_weights=1.526086956521739)
# ColorDecomposition(color=array([0.9, 0.6, 0.5]), weights=array([0.17826087, 0.91304348, 0.43478261]), components=[array([0., 0., 1.]), array([0.8, 0.5, 0.2]), array([0.39, 0.33, 0.32])], indices=[2, 6, 20], cost=0.0, sum_weights=1.526086956521739)
# ColorDecomposition(color=array([0.9, 0.6, 0.5]), weights=array([0.4, 0.1, 0.5]), components=[array([1., 0., 0.]), array([0., 1., 0.]), array([1., 1., 1.])], indices=[0, 1, 5], cost=2.6377536518327582e-30, sum_weights=0.9999999999999989)
# ColorDecomposition(color=array([0.9, 0.6, 0.5]), weights=array([0.4, 0.1, 0.5]), components=[array([1., 0., 0.]), array([0., 1., 0.]), array([1., 1., 1.])], indices=[0, 1, 5], cost=3.697785493223493e-32, sum_weights=0.9999999999999999)
# ColorDecomposition(color=array([0.9, 0.6, 0.5]), weights=array([0.4, 0.1, 0.5]), components=[array([1., 0., 0.]), array([0., 1., 0.]), array([1., 1., 1.])], indices=[0, 1, 5], cost=1.355854680848614e-31, sum_weights=1.0)
# [0.52, 0.5, 0.5]
# ColorDecomposition(color=array([0.50666667, 0.50666667, 0.50666667]), weights=array([0.50666667]), components=[array([1., 1., 1.])], indices=[5], cost=0.0002666666666666671, sum_weights=0.5066666666666667)
# ColorDecomposition(color=array([0.52, 0.5 , 0.5 ]), weights=array([0.52, 0.5 ]), components=[array([1., 0., 0.]), array([0., 1., 1.])], indices=[0, 16], cost=2.465190328815662e-32, sum_weights=1.02)
# ColorDecomposition(color=array([0.52, 0.5 , 0.5 ]), weights=array([0.2  , 0.2  , 0.508]), components=[array([0.76, 0.6 , 0.42]), array([0.57, 0.63, 0.81]), array([0.5, 0.5, 0.5])], indices=[8, 11, 19], cost=0.0, sum_weights=0.9079999999999999)
# ColorDecomposition(color=array([0.52, 0.5 , 0.5 ]), weights=array([0.2  , 0.2  , 0.508]), components=[array([0.76, 0.6 , 0.42]), array([0.57, 0.63, 0.81]), array([0.5, 0.5, 0.5])], indices=[8, 11, 19], cost=0.0, sum_weights=0.9079999999999999)
# ColorDecomposition(color=array([0.52, 0.5 , 0.5 ]), weights=array([0.02, 0.48, 0.5 ]), components=[array([1., 0., 0.]), array([0., 0., 0.]), array([1., 1., 1.])], indices=[0, 3, 5], cost=2.0954117794933126e-31, sum_weights=0.9999999999999996)
# ColorDecomposition(color=array([0.52, 0.5 , 0.5 ]), weights=array([0.02, 1.  ]), components=[array([1., 0., 0.]), array([0.5, 0.5, 0.5])], indices=[0, 19], cost=0.0, sum_weights=1.02)
# ColorDecomposition(color=array([0.52, 0.5 , 0.5 ]), weights=array([0.02, 0.02, 0.96]), components=[array([1., 0., 0.]), array([1., 1., 1.]), array([0.5, 0.5, 0.5])], indices=[0, 5, 19], cost=9.860761315262648e-32, sum_weights=1.0)
# [0.5, 0.5, 0.5]
# ColorDecomposition(color=array([0.5, 0.5, 0.5]), weights=array([1.]), components=[array([0.5, 0.5, 0.5])], indices=[19], cost=0.0, sum_weights=1.0)
# ColorDecomposition(color=array([0.5, 0.5, 0.5]), weights=array([1.]), components=[array([0.5, 0.5, 0.5])], indices=[19], cost=0.0, sum_weights=1.0)
# ColorDecomposition(color=array([0.5, 0.5, 0.5]), weights=array([1.]), components=[array([0.5, 0.5, 0.5])], indices=[19], cost=0.0, sum_weights=1.0)
# ColorDecomposition(color=array([0.5, 0.5, 0.5]), weights=array([1.]), components=[array([0.5, 0.5, 0.5])], indices=[19], cost=0.0, sum_weights=1.0)
# ColorDecomposition(color=array([0.5, 0.5, 0.5]), weights=array([1.]), components=[array([0.5, 0.5, 0.5])], indices=[19], cost=0.0, sum_weights=1.0)
# ColorDecomposition(color=array([0.5, 0.5, 0.5]), weights=array([1.]), components=[array([0.5, 0.5, 0.5])], indices=[19], cost=0.0, sum_weights=1.0)
# ColorDecomposition(color=array([0.5, 0.5, 0.5]), weights=array([1.]), components=[array([0.5, 0.5, 0.5])], indices=[19], cost=0.0, sum_weights=1.0)
# [0, 0, 0]
# ColorDecomposition(color=array([0., 0., 0.]), weights=array([1.]), components=[array([0., 0., 0.])], indices=[3], cost=0.0, sum_weights=1.0)
# ColorDecomposition(color=array([0., 0., 0.]), weights=array([1.]), components=[array([0., 0., 0.])], indices=[3], cost=0.0, sum_weights=1.0)
# ColorDecomposition(color=array([0., 0., 0.]), weights=array([1.]), components=[array([0., 0., 0.])], indices=[3], cost=0.0, sum_weights=1.0)
# ColorDecomposition(color=array([0., 0., 0.]), weights=array([1.]), components=[array([0., 0., 0.])], indices=[3], cost=0.0, sum_weights=1.0)
# ColorDecomposition(color=array([0., 0., 0.]), weights=array([1.]), components=[array([0., 0., 0.])], indices=[3], cost=0.0, sum_weights=1.0)
# ColorDecomposition(color=array([0., 0., 0.]), weights=array([1.]), components=[array([0., 0., 0.])], indices=[3], cost=0.0, sum_weights=1.0)
# ColorDecomposition(color=array([0., 0., 0.]), weights=array([1.]), components=[array([0., 0., 0.])], indices=[3], cost=0.0, sum_weights=1.0)
# [1, 1, 1]
# ColorDecomposition(color=array([1., 1., 1.]), weights=array([1.]), components=[array([1., 1., 1.])], indices=[5], cost=0.0, sum_weights=1.0)
# ColorDecomposition(color=array([1., 1., 1.]), weights=array([1.]), components=[array([1., 1., 1.])], indices=[5], cost=0.0, sum_weights=1.0)
# ColorDecomposition(color=array([1., 1., 1.]), weights=array([0.1610306 , 0.96618357, 0.28692724]), components=[array([0.21, 0.27, 0.31]), array([1.  , 0.99, 0.82]), array([0.  , 0.  , 0.55])], indices=[14, 15, 17], cost=0.0, sum_weights=1.4141414141414144)
# ColorDecomposition(color=array([1., 1., 1.]), weights=array([0.1610306 , 0.96618357, 0.28692724]), components=[array([0.21, 0.27, 0.31]), array([1.  , 0.99, 0.82]), array([0.  , 0.  , 0.55])], indices=[14, 15, 17], cost=0.0, sum_weights=1.4141414141414144)
# ColorDecomposition(color=array([1., 1., 1.]), weights=array([1.]), components=[array([1., 1., 1.])], indices=[5], cost=0.0, sum_weights=1.0)
# ColorDecomposition(color=array([1., 1., 1.]), weights=array([1.]), components=[array([1., 1., 1.])], indices=[5], cost=0.0, sum_weights=1.0)
# ColorDecomposition(color=array([1., 1., 1.]), weights=array([1.]), components=[array([1., 1., 1.])], indices=[5], cost=0.0, sum_weights=1.0)
```

---

## Using Brute-Force and bounded Minimization

This is essentially the same as above, except the now we use a more sophisticated optimization method than simple unbounded least squares.
This provides us with weights that are already bounded so there is no need for the additional code to handle that case and, most importantly, the optimal solutions are discarded solely on cost.

The approach would read:

```py
import scipy.optimize


def _err(x, A, b):
    return b - A @ x


def cost(x, A, b):
    err = _err(x, A, b)
    return np.sum(err * err)


def decompose_bf_min(
    color: Sequence,
    colors: Sequence,
    max_nums: int = 3,
    min_nums: int = 1,
    min_weights: float = 0.0, 
    max_weights: float = 1.0,
    normalize: bool = False,
) -> Optional[ColorDecomposition]:
    color = np.array(color)
    colors = np.array(colors)
    num_colors, num_channels = colors.shape
    # augment color/colors to include norm in cost
    if normalize:
        colors = np.concatenate(
            [colors, np.ones(num_colors, dtype=colors.dtype)[:, None]],
            axis=1,
        )
        color = np.concatenate([color, np.ones(1, dtype=colors.dtype)])
    # brute-force search
    best_indices = None
    best_weights = np.zeros(1)
    best_cost = np.inf
    for n in range(min_nums, max_nums + 1):
        for indices in itertools.combinations(range(num_colors), n):
            weights = np.full(n, 1 / n)
            if not np.allclose(color, 0):
                res = scipy.optimize.minimize(
                    cost,
                    weights,
                    (colors[indices, :].T, color),
                    bounds=[(min_weights, max_weights) for _ in range(n)]
                )
                weights = res.x
            curr_cost = cost(weights, colors[indices, :].T, color)
            if curr_cost <= best_cost:
                best_indices = indices
                best_weights = weights
                best_cost = curr_cost
    if best_indices is not None:
        return ColorDecomposition(
            color=(colors[best_indices, :].T @ best_weights)[:num_channels],
            weights=best_weights,
            components=[c for c in colors[best_indices, :num_channels]],
            indices=best_indices,
            cost=best_cost,
            sum_weights=np.sum(best_weights),
        )
    else:
        return None
```

which works as follows:

```py
some_colors = [[0.9, 0.6, 0.5], [0.52, 0.5, 0.5], [0.5, 0.5, 0.5], [0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1]]
# some_colors = [[0., 0., 0.]]
for color in some_colors:
    print(color)
    print(decompose_bf_min(color, colors))
    print(decompose_bf_min(color, colors, normalize=True))
# [0.9, 0.6, 0.5]
# ColorDecomposition(color=array([0.9, 0.6, 0.5]), weights=array([0.42982455, 0.2631579 , 0.70701754]), components=[array([0.8, 0.5, 0.2]), array([0.77, 0.12, 0.23]), array([0.5, 0.5, 0.5])], indices=(6, 10, 19), cost=2.3673037349051385e-17, sum_weights=1.399999995602849)
# ColorDecomposition(color=array([0.89999998, 0.60000001, 0.49999999]), weights=array([0.4       , 0.10000003, 0.49999999]), components=[array([1., 0., 0.]), array([0., 1., 0.]), array([1., 1., 1.])], indices=(0, 1, 5), cost=6.957464274781682e-16, sum_weights=1.0000000074212045)
# [0.52, 0.5, 0.5]
# ColorDecomposition(color=array([0.52, 0.5 , 0.5 ]), weights=array([0.02, 0.  , 1.  ]), components=[array([1., 0., 0.]), array([1.  , 0.99, 0.82]), array([0.5, 0.5, 0.5])], indices=(0, 15, 19), cost=2.1441410828292465e-17, sum_weights=1.019999995369513)
# ColorDecomposition(color=array([0.52000021, 0.50000018, 0.50000018]), weights=array([0.02000003, 0.02000077, 0.95999883]), components=[array([1., 0., 0.]), array([1., 1., 1.]), array([0.5, 0.5, 0.5])], indices=(0, 5, 19), cost=2.517455337509621e-13, sum_weights=0.9999996259509482)
# [0.5, 0.5, 0.5]
# ColorDecomposition(color=array([0.5, 0.5, 0.5]), weights=array([0., 0., 1.]), components=[array([0., 1., 1.]), array([1.  , 0.01, 0.24]), array([0.5, 0.5, 0.5])], indices=(16, 18, 19), cost=0.0, sum_weights=1.0)
# ColorDecomposition(color=array([0.5, 0.5, 0.5]), weights=array([0., 1., 0.]), components=[array([1.  , 0.01, 0.24]), array([0.5, 0.5, 0.5]), array([0.39, 0.33, 0.32])], indices=(18, 19, 20), cost=0.0, sum_weights=1.0)
# [0, 0, 0]
# ColorDecomposition(color=array([0., 0., 0.]), weights=array([1.]), components=[array([0., 0., 0.])], indices=(3,), cost=0.0, sum_weights=1.0)
# ColorDecomposition(color=array([0., 0., 0.]), weights=array([1., 0., 0.]), components=[array([0., 0., 0.]), array([0.  , 0.  , 0.55]), array([1.  , 0.01, 0.24])], indices=(3, 17, 18), cost=0.0, sum_weights=1.0)
# [1, 1, 1]
# ColorDecomposition(color=array([1., 1., 1.]), weights=array([1., 0., 0.]), components=[array([1., 1., 1.]), array([0., 1., 1.]), array([1.  , 0.01, 0.24])], indices=(5, 16, 18), cost=0.0, sum_weights=1.0)
# ColorDecomposition(color=array([1., 1., 1.]), weights=array([1., 0., 0.]), components=[array([1., 1., 1.]), array([1.  , 0.01, 0.24]), array([0.5, 0.5, 0.5])], indices=(5, 18, 19), cost=0.0, sum_weights=1.0)
```

Comment: The additional constraints on the proportions (summing up to 1, being in the [0, 1] range). What if The range is [0,3] and each constraint range is [0,1]? can I get a solution using this?

Comment: Can you explain to me how did u choose the appropriate colour for mixing?

Comment: What is the use case of best_linear_approx() function?

Comment: @Jeeth If you set each weight in the `[0, 1]` range, the sum being in the `[0, num_weights]` is automatic. In the function I provided, you just need to set `acc_to` to `None`. The color for mixing are choosen to pick the ones that gives the best approximation, i.e. minimum sum of squares. All of them are tried (that is what brute force means). Any other metric can be used, but it would not match what `np.linalg.lstsq()` uses.

Comment: `best_linear_approx()` finds the best weights to assign to `n` vectors (`components`), such that their linear combination (weighted sum) is as close as possible (minimizes the sum of squares) to the `target` vector.

Comment: The problem I'm facing with your code is that if I give a colour code which is already there in the list of colours it's still trying to reach the target colour using different colours rather than selecting the colour code which already in it. can you help me out with this? I have set the 'acc_to' to 'None'

Comment: Instead of the closest colours what is it that you have used to get the best selected?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247871/discussion-between-jeeth-and-norok2).

Answer (score 2):

You can make a system of equations to come up with a weighting vector which will tell you the combination of the three colors which exactly equals the input. The form of this is Ax=b, where A is the color matrix, x are the unknown variables to solve, and b is the color target. You have already calculated the 'A' in this situation, it just needs to be transposed. Of course, you also have your target color. However, this is not mapped to the fuzzy set (i.e. from 0 to 1 inclusive). If, for instance, you can only vary the intensity (from 0 to 1 or equivalently 0% to 100%) of the three colors to achieve this input color, then this approach is not sufficient. If you need each of the weighting values to be between 0 and 1, then you can solve a linear program in which you specify the constraints of 0<=w<=1 on the weights. That seems a little complicated for this, but it can be done if that's an interest.

Edit: I added the linear program to solve the problem. Linear programs are used to solve complex optimization problems where there are constraints that are placed on the variables in the system of equations. They are very powerful and can accomplish a lot. Unfortunately, it raises the complexity of the code quite a bit. Also, just to let you know, there is no guarantee that there will be a solution in which all the variables are in the set [0,1]. I believe in this particular example, it is not possible, but it does get very close.

```
import numpy as np

# target vector
input_color = np.array([.52, .5, .5])
input_color = np.reshape(input_color, (1, len(input_color))).T

# create color matrix with 3 chosen colors
color_1 = np.array([.5, .5, .5])
color_2 = np.array([.76, .6, .42])
color_3 = np.array([.8, .5, .2])
C = np.vstack([color_1, color_2, color_3]).T

# use linear algebra to solve for variables
weights = np.matmul(np.linalg.pinv(C),input_color)

# show that the correct values for each color were calculated
print(weights[0]*color_1 + weights[1]*color_2 + weights[2]*color_3)




from scipy.optimize import linprog

color_1 = np.array([.5, .5, .5])
color_2 = np.array([.76, .6, .42])
color_3 = np.array([.8, .5, .2])

# make variables greater than zero
ineq_1 = np.array([-1, 0, 0])
ineq_2 = np.array([0, -1, 0])
ineq_3 = np.array([0, 0, -1])

# make variables less than or equal to one
ineq_4 = np.array([1, 0, 0])
ineq_5 = np.array([0, 1, 0])
ineq_6 = np.array([0, 0, 1])

C = np.vstack([color_1, color_2, color_3]).T
C = np.vstack([C, ineq_1, ineq_2, ineq_3, ineq_4, ineq_5, ineq_6])

A = C

input_color = np.array([.52, .5, .5])
b = np.concatenate((input_color, np.array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1])),axis=0)
b = np.reshape(b, (1, len(b))).T

# scipy minimizes, so maximize by multiplying by -1
c = -1*np.array([1, 1, 1])


# Visually, what we have right now is

# maximize f = x1 + x2 + x3
#    color_1_red*x1 + color_2_red*x2 + color_3_red*x3 <= input_color_red
#    color_1_gre*x1 + color_2_gre*x2 + color_3_gre*x3 <= input_color_gre
#    color_1_blu*x1 + color_2_blu*x2 + color_3_blu*x3 <= input_color_blu
#    x1 >= 0
#    x2 >= 0
#    x3 >= 0
#    x1 <= 1
#    x2 <= 1
#    x3 <= 1

# As you'll notice, we have the original system of equations in our constraint
#  on the system. However, we have added the constraints that the variables
#  must be in the set [0,1]. We maximize the variables because linear programs
#  are made simpler when the system of equations are less than or equal to.


# calculate optimal variables with constraints
res = linprog(c, A_ub=A, b_ub=b)

print(res.x)

print(res.x[0]*color_1 + res.x[1]*color_2 + res.x[2]*color_3)
```

Comment: Actually I need the weights value to be in between 0 to 1 can you help me out here, Can you tell me how i can achieve it what method i can use to achieve it. What do you mean by linear program can you tell me how I can use it to achieve the required weights.

Comment: the codes are not the same as the input codes, I was actually looking for a method where I can get the output codes the same as the input. Thanks for trying to help me out but, this is not what I was looking for.

Comment: And the Important thing is I want to know how much percentage of each colour code is required to get the input colour code. What I'm actually trying to get here is to mix colours So, I need to find how much percentage of each color is required to get the input Color.

Comment: It is possible to guarantee the weights to be in the `[0, 1]` range, as long as the base vector are in the `[0, 1]` range and the vectors are ortho-normal. For example, the canonical base (i.e. `[1, 0, 0]`, `[0, 1, 0]` and `[0, 0, 1]`) will achieve that. If the vectors are not orthonormal you cannot guarantee that, but you can search for the closest vectors which are a span of any other vector. @Jeeth you really need to define what your priorities are.

Comment: @norok2 what I'm trying to achieve is. I am trying to create a model where there are 21 different colours in it and then given a colour as an input my code should select one, two or three closest colours and then tell me how much percentage each of those closest colours will give me the input colour.  I have found the closest colours but, where I'm stuck is I'm unable to figure out a way how to find how much percentage of each of those closest colours will give me the colour that I have given as input.

Comment: @Jeeth You might be interested in some [geometric interpretations of this problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/544946/determine-if-projection-of-3d-point-onto-plane-is-within-a-triangle). I think in general you can't guarantee that this is true for the nearest three points. I suspect this being true is related to your points being vertexes of a convex polyhedra. So you might like to have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30380394/how-do-i-determine-if-a-polyhedron-is-convex) and apply it to your points.